# Swift - Table view shrinks in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

When I push from Settings view controller into a new view controller which contains table view, it is shrinking. At the same time, when given as initial view controller, it is appearing correctly. The issue came up after using scroll view in the settings view controller.

Please find the preview of settings view controller here:

[image: screenshot]

While running the simulator, we got the following shrunk output:

[image: simulator screenshot]

How do I resolve this so that I will get the full table view?

Thanks

Comment: did you try Opaque navigation bar ?

Comment: Can you please let me know where should I use that? Is it for the Table view?

Comment: Check this link : https://screencast.com/t/X67WUFcGU

Comment: have you applied auto layout constraints correctly?

Comment: @MuseerAnsari Just trying that :)

Comment: @NileshPol Yeah. When the view is given as initial view controller, I got it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried removing the Navigation bar in the page and adding it again from the beginning. It worked!!! :)

Guess the problem was with the previous navigation bar.

Thanks for all the help!!!

I will close the thread after 6 hours, since it allows to close my own thread only after that time..